# Rails 3.2.1 - Getting Javascript variables/data to Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I'm working on a `Rails 3.2.1` app and would like to pass some Javascript variables to the Rails controller.  Here are some more details:

my js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PauWy/475/

and what fiddle doesn't show, a jQuery UI sortable:  `$("#menu-items").sortable();`

I would like to work with the following information in my Rails 'execute' method in the ThingsController for each item:

1. Whether or not the item is visible   (I think I should do something like $('#item_1).is(':visible')
2. Which one of the following is displayed - "Add", "Reduce", or neither
3. the id of the item
4. the order/position of the item in the sortable list

My take would be to send an AJAX with the above data to the 'things/execute' action, and somehow route it and respond_to the incoming AJAX.

I know vaguely how some bits and pieces should look like, but I'm having a hard time putting everything together.  Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: On a side note, please upgrade to the latest 3.2.x release before putting this on an internet site, or it *will* get hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to parse you HTML to get information from it

Example

**HTML :**

```
<div id="my_content">
  <div id="div1" class="reduce" style="visibility: visible;"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="add" style="visibility: visible;"></div>
  <div id="div3" class="add" style="visibility: visible;"></div>
  <div id="div4" class="reduce" style="visibility: visible;"></div>

  <div id="div5" class="reduce" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
  <div id="div6" class="add" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
  <div id="div7" class="add" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
  <div id="div8" class="reduce" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can parse it to JSON (using jQuery) :

**Javascript :**

```
var parsed_data = {}
var order = 1

$('#my_content > div').each(function() {
  // Some if else
  var element_class = $(this).hasClass('reduce') ? 'reduce' : 
                    ( $(this).hasClass('add')    ? 'add' : 'unkown')

  parsed_data['data'+ order] = {
    element_id:    $(this).attr('id'),
    display_class: element_class,
    visibility:    $(this).css('visibility'),
  }

  order++
})
```

Then you call your controller with AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<CONTROLLER_URL>",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json', // data returned, not data sent
  data: parsed_data
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log('Done')
})
```

**Ruby Controller :**

```
def your_controller_function
  params.each do |key, div|
    print "DIV N°#{key}"
    print "  Id #{element_id}"
    print "  Displayed class #{display_class}"
    print "  Visibility #{visibility}"
  end
end
```

I hope it's not too messy and it helped.